# i tried to make a simple python auto google search but its not working im not sure why

Tags: python, web, request, sys

i dont know what to try because im not getting any error messages its just blank when i run it, i was following along with a guy on youtube and his worked

```
import requests
import bs4
import sys
import webbrowser

search = 'savage'
res = requests.get(f'https://google.com/search?q={search}')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
linkelem = soup.select('.r a')
linkstoopen = min(5, len(linkelem))

for i in range(linkstoopen):
    webbrowser.open('https://google.com', linkelem[i].get('href'))
```

it is supposed to open up the top 5 results for "savage" on google

Comment: how old is  this tutorial ? Maybe Google changed HTML and code doesn't fit to HTML. Google uses JavaScript to add elements on page but BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript. Google sends different HTML when browser (or script) doesn't use JavaScript. Besides Google doesn't like scripts/bots and it check header 'User-Agent` in requests and it can send captcha to block scripts/bots. Better display `res.text` to see what you get. Or you can save `res.text` in file and open it in browser to see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as furas suggested I think the result html code might have changed since the tutorial was made.

I got it to work with two changes to your code:

Change the line:

```
linkelem = soup.select('.r a')
```

to

```
linkelem = []
for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "jfp3ef"}):
    for link in div.select("a"):
        linkelem.append(link)
```

Looking at the respons we get from Google we see that the result links is in a div with the class name jfp3ef.

Then you should add the element to the google url in the last loop

```
webbrowser.open('https://google.com' + linkelem[i].get('href'))
```